# Share insert/update date between entities (parent children)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

Each of my entities tables have a timestamp column to keep the creation date or the last update date.

Is there an easy way with spring data, jpa and hibernate to insert the same date in all my persisted objects within a transaction without having to set it manually to every object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JPA API, then have a look at @PrePersist annotation. This needs to be on a method in Entity ( child or for better use create a base entity and put it there)

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
if(createDate == null) {
    createDate = new Date();
}
updateDate = new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write and bind a `org.hibernate.event.spi.PreInsertEventListener` which can set the date. You might need to have your entities implement a common interface which exposes a `setDate` method since the `PreInsertEvent` only exposes an `Object`.

You can also implement `org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEventListener` in the same way to update the date on update.

In terms of getting access to the date, you could set it on a thread local at the start of your transaction and then access it in the listener.